# Set axis to specific value in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I would like to specify the value of my axis on my imageItem.

This is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = pg.mkQApp('Example')

layout = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
plot_item = pg.PlotItem(title="")
image_item = pg.ImageItem()
plot_item.addItem(image_item)
layout.addItem(plot_item)

data = np.random.rand(10,10)
image_item.setImage(data)

axb = pg.graphicsItems.AxisItem.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
axb.setRange(-100,100)
plot_item.setAxisItems(axisItems={'bottom': axb})

if __name__ == '__main__':
   pg.exec()
```

This code does not work because the bottom axis is not between -100 and 100.

Moreover, is it possible to give an entire array ? In order to have my bottom axis corresponding to [-100,-75,-50,-25,0,25,50,75,100] (or np.linspace(-100,100,100))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ImageItem you should set Transform. See the example on [ImageItem documentation.](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/graphicsItems/imageitem.html#examples)